# How do I avoid a file not found error installing a tarball with pip?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm building a local python package

```
cd <source dir>
python ./setup.py sdist
```

When I try and install it with pip, it attempts to delete a file that's not present, and fails.

```
pip install --verbose dist/pl_zenoss_handler-0.1.1.tar.gz
Unpacking ./dist/pl_zenoss_handler-0.1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-QohNov-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///Users/travis.bear/p4/depot/service/python/_pl_zenoss_handler/dist/pl_zenoss_handler-0.1.1.tar.gz
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/pl_zenoss_handler.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/pl_zenoss_handler.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/pl_zenoss_handler.egg-info/top_level.txt

<... much output deleted for brevity ... >

creating build/scripts-2.7

error: file '/private/tmp/pip-QohNov-build/bin/zen_handler' does not exist

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-QohNov-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uIoyIG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-QohNov-build
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 279, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1380, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 699, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-QohNov-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uIoyIG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/travis.bear/venv/zenoss/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-QohNov-build

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/travis.bear/.pip/pip.log
```

Here is the setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

readme = open('README.rst').read()
history = open('HISTORY.rst').read().replace('.. :changelog:', '')

setup(
    name='pl_zenoss_handler',
    version='0.1.1',
    description='Sensu handler for Zenoss',
    long_description=readme + '\n\n' + history,
    author='Travis Bear',
    author_email='<snip>',
    url='<snip>',
    packages=[
        'zen_handler',
    ],
    scripts=['bin/zen_handler'],
    install_requires=[
    ],
    license="BSD",
    keywords='zenoss sensu'
)
```

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but have you tried `touch`ing the unexisting file as a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem: `bin/zen_handler` file missing in distribution package

The problem is, that your `setup.py` is asking for use of file in `bin/zen_handler` and in your distribution gz file it is missing.

### How it went?

1. you have the `bin/zen_handler` in your source tree
2. your `setup.py` defines conditions for creating distribution package
3. you create the distribution plackage
4. you use the distribution package for installing the program
5. distribution package does not contain `bin/zen_handler` and fails.

You shall check, if `gz` file contains the `bin/zen_handler`. I will assume, it is not present.

The reason is, that as it is not part of python package `zen_handler` itself, it is not packaged into distribution.

### Resolution

#### Declare this non-python file to be part of distribution

Find the option for setup.py, which will declare even the `bin/zen_handler` as part of the distribution package. This will probably mean editing `MANIFEST.in` file (adding that file there) and/or using parameter `include_package_data`.

#### (preferred) Install the script using `entry_points`

Instead of using paremater `scripts`, use `entry_point` as described in [Automatic Script Creation](http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation). As this is using purely package python source code, it does not require existence of files outside.

I recommend this solution, even though it requires little modification in your code.